# What is the "guilty smile of a blind man"?

Tags: belarusian-language

In the beginning of *Khatyn*, we are introduced to a man with dark glasses and a white cane whose "mouth quivered with the guilty smile of a blind man." He's later said to have the "fixed quiet smile of a blind man." I'm slightly baffled by this. For one thing, they appear contradictory to each other. For another thing, why would a blind man necessarily have a "guilty smile"? Can someone explain these quotes to me?

Comment: I don't know, but obviously a blind person can't tell whether or not other people are smiling, so maybe he was slightly embarrassed in case the people round him had solemn faces?